# How to pass quarterly values dynamically inside "where" clause according to date in postgresql query

Tags: php, postgresql-9.4

I have provided value (4th) inside the "where" clause manually. See the query below.But I want to provide more than one quarterly value inside the "where" clause dynamically.And quarterly values will be depend on month.when will automatically change then quarterly values will also automatically changed and will be used as condition of where claus.
So,How do I provide quarterly values dynamically.

(Discription:total 4 quarterly in one year.per quarterly =3 month.So january to march is 1st quarterly, April to jun is 2nd quarterly, july to september is 3rd quarterly and october to december is 4th quarterly.Now    so 4 quarterly =12 month or 1 year.Now I have to always take 2 quarterly.one quarterly will depend on current 3month and other quarterly will be previous 3 month.example:As per quarterly = 3 month.So current quarterly will be for month of april to jun(2nd quarterly)  .and previous quarterly will be for january to march(1st quarterly) .So we will get quarterly column values 2nd and 1st. Now we have to query and use 2nd and 1st dynamicaly as codition of where clause.because this(2nd &1st) quarterly values will depend on month.when month will be automatically changed then quarterly values also will be automatically changed.then values of quarterly will be 3rd  and 2nd.And then this two quarterly values will replace in previous quarterly values inside where clause  in query.thus will continue.)

`$values = DB::table('mnw.monitorevents')
 ->where('quarterly', '=','4th')
 ->first();`

Comment: Can you please show us an example of what the data structure looks like which you want to drive the query? Is it an array of `columns` and `values`?

Comment: more than one values will be in where clause but column is ony one quarterly

Comment: Edit your question and show us a formatted example, please.

Comment: Didn't you understand my question.I will edit for you

Comment: Show us a sample of the _dynamic_ data that you want to drive the query. From your comments sounds like an example would be `array('4th', '8th', '11th', '21st')`. Is that right or is it `array('quaterly' => array('4th', '8th', '11th', '21st'), 'datestart' => array('2018-12-02', '2018-12-25'))`? Please update your question with _formatted samples_.

Comment: I have written some text in my question.please see and read.I hope you will understand if not then please reply why you are not understanding then I will update again for you.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the quarter value from the current date.

`date('n')` returns the month number. Divide the month number by 3 and round up to get the quarter, then subtract 1 to make this a zero-based index. Then use this as the index into an array of the quarter names you're using in the database column.

```
$quarters = ["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th"];
$current_quarter_num = ceil(date('n') / 3) - 1;
$current_quarter = $quarters[$current_quarter_num];
$current_values = DB::table('mnw.monitorevents')
 ->where('quarterly', '=',$current_quarter)
 ->where('datestart','=','2018-12-02')
 ->first();
$previous_quarter_num = ($current_quarter_num + 3) % 4;
$previous_quarter = $quarters[$previous_quarter_num];
$previous_values = DB::table('mnw.monitorevents')
 ->where('quarterly', '=',$previous_quarter)
 ->where('datestart','=','2018-12-02')
 ->first();
```

Comment: Barmar,I have to pass more than one value inside where clause.and value can be anything from quarterly column.so how can i write query.                                            you have used value 4th manually in variable but value will be dynamic in variable.

Comment: You can set the variables any way you want, I just used literals for examples.

Comment: Like `$column = $_POST['column'];`

Comment: I understand you gave example.but I can't understand,how can i write query properly.so can you please write query.if in future value is changed but will not show any problem.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to get these dynamic values from user input.

Comment: Barmar,values will come from table not user input.So from where and how you get $_POST. $column = $_POST['column'];
$value = $_POST['value'];

Comment: You can set the variables any way you want, it's not important to the answer.

Comment: This was just an example of one way to set them, you can use `$row['column']` from a query result.

Comment: However, if it's just the values coming from another database table, you should probably be using a join, not a dynamic `where`.

Comment: I don't know, you haven't explained clearly where these dynamic values are coming from. My answer explains a general method, a competent programmer should be able to figure out the specifics for a particular application.

Comment: Rather than asking me these vague questions, edit the question and show a specific example.

Comment: Barmar,By $row['column'],I will write column name within third bracket [ ].But How can i pass quarterly values by $row['value']. which values and how will i write quarterly values within third bracket[ ].

Comment: Please stop asking questions and edit the question to show what you're trying to do.

Comment: values will come from database table.And values will be changed in future.So If values is changed but will not show any error in where clause.So if we pass values dynamically in where clause then if values is changed,still will not show any probem.I hope you understand

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm just going to ignore your questions.

Comment: I have written some text in my question.please see and read.I hope you will understand if not then please reply why you are not understanding then I will update again for you.

Comment: it seems like your real question is how to figure out the quarter name from the current date. It would be easier if you stored quarters as numbers in the table, instead of strings like `4th`.

Comment: If I var_dump($current_values); then value is not showing accurately.quarterly value is showing "2nd" but quarterly value will be 1st.because January to March is 1st quarterly.so current quarterly value will be 1st. April to Jun is 2nd quarterly.As jun Month is not finished yet. so current quarterly value will show 1st and previous quarterly value will be 4th for October to December month.because previous month is October to December(2018) than January to March(2019). So Quarterly column value is not coming accurately and other values of same row are not coming accurately.

Comment: I think I've fixed the way I calculate the quarter. I shouldn't be subtracting 1 from the month, I have to round the division up and then subtract 1 from that.

Answer (score 0):

Discarded previous answer based on the updated question.
Sounds like you want to determine the *current* and *previous* quarter based on the current date. Is that right?

You can use the Carbon package which comes with Laravel to get these values. You can even get the first and last dates for the quarter. Do a search for "quarter" [in the docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

```
<?php
use Carbon\Carbon;

...

$today = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

var_dump([
    $today->copy()->quarter,
    $today->copy()->firstOfQuarter(),
    $today->copy()->lastOfQuarter(),
    $today->copy()->subQuarter(1)->quarter,
    $today->copy()->subQuarter(1)->firstOfQuarter(),
    $today->copy()->subQuarter(1)->lastOfQuarter(),
]);

// Output formatted for readability.
// array (size=6)
//   0 => 2
//   1 => 2019-04-01 00:00:00.328373
//   2 => 2019-06-30 00:00:00.328373
//   3 => 1
//   4 => 2019-01-01 00:00:00.328373
//   5 => 2019-03-31 00:00:00.328373
```

You could then use quarter # or dates in your query. Does that answer your question?

Comment: waterloomatt,I have to pass more than one value inside where clause.and value can be anything and changed from quarterly column.which I do not know.so if I pass column value in variable then have to pass dynamically.so that,if value changed in future then do not show problem.so how can i write query.